# Varianten zu "Ich schickte jemanden Bier holen"

Tags: usage

[Dem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/schicken) zufolge kann man sagen

> Ich schickte Paul Bier holen.

Kann man auch sagen

> (a) Ich schickte Paul, Bier zu holen.

und

> (b) Ich schickte Paul zum Bierholen.

? Wenn so, welche Variante ist am üblichsten?

Ein bisschen Hintergrund: Ich war vom Ausgangssatz überrascht, denn auf Englisch sagt man nicht

> I sent Paul get a beer.

sondern

> I sent Paul to get a beer.

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/why-do-some-dictionaries-have-rad-fahren-and-others-radfahren-is-rad-a-separabl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nach dem verlinkte Wörterbuch und Duden Online regiert "schicken" einen Infinitiv ohne zu. "Ich schicke Paul Bier zu holen" würde ich in der Umgangssprache dennoch gelten lassen.

Mir erscheint jedoch "Ich schickte Paul, um Bier zu holen" vertrauter. Sprachbeleg:

> Immer zu Weihnachten - er muss lachen, wenn er heute davon erzählt - schickte man ihn auf einen wackligen Kirchturm, um das neue Jahr mit Trompetenklängen zu begrüßen.
>   Braunschweiger Zeitung, 05.01.2013, Ressort: WN-Lok; Die Suche nach dem Chor 2.0

Aus dem Zusammenhang wird meist eindeutig klar, wer wen schickt um was zu tun:

> Sie schickten ihr Kind ins Ferienlager, um Zeit für sich zu haben.

"Ich schickte Paul zum Bierholen", d. H. Substantivierung des Verbs, würde ich vermeiden, allein schon um mich um die Frage der Schreibung herumzudrücken.

Es stellt sich aber die Frage, inwieweit "schicken" in diesem Zusammenhang überhaupt gebräuchlich ist, und nicht:

> Ich ließ ihn Bier holen.

Wie die Erörterung zeigt, ist "schicken" ist in diesem Zusammenhang recht sperrig.

**Anmerkung**: Emanuel hat recht insoweit, dass "ließ" formal klingt, jedoch halte ich das Präteritum dafür verantwortlich. Im Alltag wird man eher "Ich hab' ihn Bier holen geschickt" oder "Ich hab' ihn Bier holen lassen"; das dürfte auch meist richtig sein, weil entweder Paul weg ist oder das Bier bereits auf dem Tisch steht und damit das Ergebnis der Handlung betont wird.

Comment: Sorry, aber ich finde "lassen" viel zu formell. Ich schicke Paul um Bier zu holen ist semantisch falsch, wenn man von der Standardbedeutung der um-Struktur ausgeht. Du tust etwas so dass du etwas anderes tun kannst. Du schickst also Paul irgendwohin, damit du selber Bier holen gehen kannst.

Comment: @Emanuel: Richtig, ich habe es als falsch markiert.

Comment: @Emanuel: Sehe es doch anders, siehe Begründung, außerdem die Anmerkung zum formalen Klang.

Comment: Vielleicht ist auch was mir an "Ich schicke Paul, um Bier zu holen" aufstößt die Tatsache, dass der Ort fehlt während er in deinen anderen Beispielen vorhanden ist (auf den Kirchturm, in Ferienlager). "Ich schicke Paul zur Tanke, um Bier zu holen" klingt ok für mich. "Ich schicke Paul, um Bier zu holen" klingt entweder alt oder falsch. Was "schicken" und "lassen" angeht, so würde ich sie nie gegeneinander austauschen. Es gibt sowohl semantische als auch tonale Unterschiede.

Answer (score 2):

Sowohl in *Duden – Deutsches Universalwörterbuch* als auch in *Duden – Das Stilwörterbuch* werden für „jemanden schicken“ mit der Bedeutung „jemanden etwas tun heißen; jemanden veranlassen, sich zu einem bestimmten Zweck, mit einem Auftrag o. Ä. an einen bestimmten Ort zu begeben“ zwei mögliche Formulierungen genannt:

> <jemanden schicken; mit Infinitiv> jemanden einkaufen schicken
>
> <jemanden zu jemandem, etwas schicken> jemanden zum Einkaufen schicken

Der Fall, dass „schicken“ zusammen mit dem Infinitiv mit „zu“ verwendet wird, kann allerdings auch auftreten:

> sie wurde geschickt, mir zu helfen

Dieser Satz bedeutet

> sie wurde geschickt, um mir zu helfen
> sie wurde geschickt, damit sie mir hilft

und resultiert daraus, dass die Konjunktion „um“, die einen finalen Infinitiv einleitet, manchmal weggelassen werden kann:

> sie wurde geschickt, [um] mir zu helfen

Bemerkenswert ist dabei noch, dass sich der mit „um zu“ eingeleitete Infinitiv nach „schicken“ auf das Objekt des übergeordneten Satzes beziehen kann:

> ich habe sie zum Bäcker geschickt, um Brötchen zu holen